# How to get NULL from LINQ When no value found in the joining tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning LINQ Queries. And in one of my ASP.Net MVC 5 project I am trying the query but it is not giving desired result. So, I have one to many relationship between Referral and Instance table. Below is the Model.

Referral:

```
public class Referral
{
    public Referral()
    {
        Instances = new Collection<Instance>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int ReferralId { get; set; }
    public int CandidateId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Instance> Instances { get; set; }
}
```

Instance Model

```
public class Instance
{
    [Key]
    public int InstanceId { get; set; }
    public string ReferralStatus { get; set; }
    public int ReferralId { get; set; }
    public string ReferrerId { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my controller Action

```
  [HttpPost]
  public JsonResult CheckForExistingReferral(ReferralViewModel viewModel)
  {
     bool hasPreviousRequest = false;
     var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
     var referral = _context.Referrals
    .Where(r => (r.CandidateId == candidateId) && r.Instances
    .Any(e => (e.ReferrerId != null) && (e.ReferralStatus == "Referred")));
          // some logic
        }
```

**DB Status:**

I have NO DATA in Instance Table as of now. And I have some data in Referrals Table.

Referrals Table:

```
ReferralId      CandidateId

1                    3
```

Instance Table:

```
NO DATA
```

Question: Why my LINQ Query is not returning NULL. As there is no matching END RESULT Record. I want the above LINQ Query to return NULL.

Comment: `hasPreviousRequest = referral != null;` I will do something like this

Comment: @Icepickle: Sir, I am new to LINQ. Can you kindly guide me how to make sure I get NULL from my LINQ

Comment: Wait, I think I read your inner query wrong :) It's a bit confusing to see the any on the same place of indentation though it is part of the where query)

Comment: @Icepickle: I don't think I need to use `Any`. But how to get result set then?

Comment: A linq query that returns a collection will never return `null` - just an empty collection

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Ohh. Then I should add `SingleOrDefault`

Comment: Or `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: If you add `SingleOrDefault` you might have a problem when more candidates are there, just using `Any` would give you true or false (unless ofcourse you want to do something with the results :))

Comment: I don't want to do anything with value, I just want to see if result set has any value or not, So, I can manage with true or false. But my LINQ is not giving any bool value also. With current scenario I am expecting "false".

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Sir, With the use of 'SIngleOrDefault' I am  getting NULL Values. And I get what I wanted. But If I wanted it to return Bool. How to modify the LINQ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what your want, but best guess is to just replace `.Where(` with `.Any(`

Comment: I see. Now my entire statement will give boolean result. I understood. :) Thanks as always. :)

Comment: I am curious what you wanted if there was a result

Comment: @Worthy7: I will have a check like `hasPreviousRequest = referral != null;`. And if it is true and then I would have shown a pop up to user stating that "The similar Referral request is already present. Are you sure you want to overwrite"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to say to return the record at the end. Otherwise, you are just making a query.

```
var referral = _context.Referrals
    .Where(r => (r.CandidateId == candidateId) && r.Instances
    .Any(e => (e.ReferrerId != null) && (e.ReferralStatus == "Referred")))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now just check `referral != null`.